# Replace State Component with Functional Component using Hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to replace this code from State Component  with Functional component and React Hooks

```
state = {
    todos: [],
  };

 componentDidMount() {

        fire
          .firestore()
          .collection("todos")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
              if (change.type === "added") {
                let newTodo = change.doc.data();
                this.setState({
                  todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo],
                });
              }
            });
          });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("todos")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            let newTodo = change.doc.data();
            setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
          }
        });
      });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>{/* ... */}</div>
 )
}
```

Obviously, you should [read the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) about functional components and the difference between class components.

Comment: There's no `this.state` in functional components, this should not work

Comment: In this case state is undefined.But even if i try "setTodos([...todos, newTodo]) ", it rerenders only the newTodo and not the previous ones.

Comment: Typo, sorry will fix

Comment: @DarioMitsev  can you provide more detail? Is there an action you are firing to try and update todos?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you have this `snapshot.doChanges()` stuff or what it i supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {

        fire
          .firestore()
          .collection("todos")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
              if (change.type === "added") {
                let newTodo = change.doc.data();
                setTodos((prevTodos) => [...prevTodos, newTodo]);
              }
            });
          });
      }
    });

}, [])
```

If this approach would have problems with rerender, try to wrap inner code in useCallback hook:

```
     const makeTodos = useCallback(() => {
        fire
          .firestore()
          .collection("todos")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
              if (change.type === "added") {
                let newTodo = change.doc.data();
                setTodos((prevTodos) => [...prevTodos, newTodo]);
              }
            });
          });
      }
    });
  }, [])
```

Then call this function in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  makeTodos();
}, [])
```

usseEffect, useState, and useCallback you can import from react:

```
Import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback}  from 'react'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
           fire
          .firestore()
          .collection("todos")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
              if (change.type === "added") {
                let newTodo = change.doc.data();
                setTodos(prevTodos => ([...prevTodos, newTodo]));
              }
            });
          });
}, [])
```